# No payment requested on IRCTC registration and now can't book trains

Tags: irctc

Any ideas why I wasn't asked for payment when registering with IRCRC with an overseas phone number? Now I cannot log in using an OTP so can't book any trains. I can log in using the code below the picture on the login page but if I tick login using OTP it comes up with 'international user OTP login facility is not available'. If I don't tick the OTP box I can see my name on the right hand side but when I press 'book' it doesn nothing. Any ideas what I need to do to get an OTP or how I pay for it?

Comment: Have you contacted IRCTC about this? Their mail ID is care[AT]irctc[DOT]co[DOT]in.

Comment: Yes I have sent several emails back and forth but it does not seem to be an easy question for them to answer. I have now requested they resend an OTP but I really have no idea if that is the thing to ask for.

Comment: I am unable to fully understand the question. While registering for IRCTC, AFAIK you don't have to mandatorily specify any payment option. Login using OTP isn't available for non Indian cellphones as specified by the error. Your only option is to login via username/password/captcha (which proceeds correctly). `when I press 'book' it doesn nothing` - This part can really be explained better - DO you search for train and then "Check Availability and Fare" and then you can't click on "Book Now" option because I don't see a "Book" link on the website. Can you add a few screenshots maybe?

Comment: Yes sorry, I did not make it clear, it was indeed the 'Book Now' option that I meant. Once I have logged in using the username, password and captcha, I can see my name when I click at the top right of the page so I am logged in

Comment: Continued..... however when I search for my train, select 'check availability and fare' and press the 'book now' button it does nothing. There is a 'please wait' sign and a circle that spins for a few seconds and then it returns to the same screen, with the 'book now' options on it. I have tried to add a screen print here but it won't let me paste it in 
I thought that if I used a non Indian mobile I was required to pay a small fee of 100 INR +GST. Because I did not have any prompt to pay this, my account is incomplete. I will paste what the email said that I received back from IRCTC

Comment: We would like to inform you that as per your user id your payment is pending so, please complete your payment . 
International Users to pay registration/mobile updation fees for the mobile numbers with ISD code other than 91 and i.e.Rs.100 +GST" 
Users with residence country other than India and ISD other than 91are denoted as International Users. These users now can register with their ISD numbers on sign up form. After registration you are asked to pay Fees on first login.The payment option available is AtomPG.After payment, you are asked to verify their mobile using OTPsent on your mobile

Comment: If IRCTC can't help you via their support emails (etc) I'm not sure what a bunch of random internet strangers around the globe can do about it.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to add all this info there.